# How can I undo the Lock Guides default setting in AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, guides

How can I undo the Lock Guides default setting in AI? It seems that Indesign also has the guides locked by default. How can I change this default setting? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Illustrator CS5 and CS6 this setting is persistent. So if you uncheck it and restart Illustrator it is still unchecked the next time you do things. So the default setting is the last used setting, so you change the default by changing the setting. Now for reasons beyond scope I can not say whether this is true on CC versions.

It is also possible to lock users out of being able to write to the settings file, in which case you can not do it even if you wanted to. If this is the case then you should be talking to your system admin.

Further it is also possible to manually alter the settings file, the `AIPrefs` file to be exact. The key value seems to be `/editableGuides`.